# EMM, Supremum and Expectation

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, probability

I asked this question on MSE recently.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922347/supremum-and-expectation

I want to prove this when $\mathcal{M}$ is a set of equivalent martingale measure.

**Problem setting**

Let $\Omega$ be a finite set, and $\mathbb{M}$ be a non-arbitrage **incomplete** discrete($t=0,\cdots,T$) market on $(\Omega ,2^{\Omega},P,\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_t)(\forall \omega, P(\{\omega\})>0,\mathcal{F}_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\})$ with a price process $S_t$ and a dividend process $\delta_t$. Assume that $\mathbb{M}$ has a numeraire $N$, and let $\mathcal{E}_N$ be a set of EMM w.r.t. $N$.

For any random variable $X$, does

$\displaystyle \sup_{Q\in \mathcal{E}_N}E^Q[\sup_{Q'\in \mathcal{E}_N}E^{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F_1}]]=\sup_{Q\in\mathcal{E}_N}E^Q[X]$

hold?

**My attempt**

It is easy to see that

$\sup_{Q\in \mathcal{E}_N}E^Q[\sup_{Q'\in \mathcal{E}_N}E^{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F_1}]]\geq\sup_{Q\in\mathcal{E}_N}E^Q[X]$

holds by exactly the same procedure as in the MSE post.

However, I have been unable to prove that $\forall \omega\in \Omega, \forall \epsilon>0, \exists Q_{\epsilon}\in\mathcal{E}_N$ s.t. $Q_{\epsilon}(\{\omega\})>1-\epsilon$, which is a key proposition in the MSE post.

Any help? I am new to quantitative finance so there may be some weird notation.